# What is the purpose of ADD BX,2 in this code?

Tags: arrays, recursion, assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to understand this recursion code, but I got confused about what is the purpose of `add bx, 2`. I've put a mark to the relevant line. As I understand we have to increment the pointer pointing at the array with the values but why are we adding 2 and not 1?

```
    .model small
    .stack 100
    .data
     arr dw 38, 39, 90, 94, 13, 24, 53, 59, 63
     size dw 9
     result dw ?
    .code
    func proc
     push bp
     mov bp, sp
     push ax
     push bx
     push cx
     push dx
     mov cx, [bp+4]
     mov bx, [bp+6]
     mov ax, [bx]
     cmp cx, 1
     ja more
     mov [bp+6], ax
     jmp done
    more:

     **add bx, 2**

     push bx
     dec cx
     push cx
     call func
     pop dx
     cmp dx, ax
     jg greater
     mov [bp+6], ax
     jmp done
    greater:
     mov [bp+6], dx
    done:
     pop dx
     pop cx
     pop bx
     pop ax
     pop bp
     ret 2
    func endp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As i understand we have to increment the pointer pointing at the array with the values but why we are adding 2 and not 1?

If I understand correctly, `BX` points to the address of an element in an array containing 16-bit values.

The instruction `mov ax, [bx]` shows you that the elements are 16-bit values and not 8- or 32-bit values. A 16-bit value is 2 bytes long.

On most CPUs (there are exceptions like the TMS 320 or the TMS 9900) the difference between the addresses of two elements in an array is `n` if the element is `n` bytes long.

So if `x` is the address of an element in an array containing 16-bit values and `y` is the address of the next element, then `y-x=2`.

Therefore two must be added to `BX` to get the address of the next element.

Comment: Thanks! now I understand since each element of the array is word and not a byte!

Answer (score 2):

Note the `push bx` / ... / `call func` afterwards: this is a recursive function, and it's passing `bx+2` to the next invocation.

I think BX is getting used as pointer, and there's an `arr` which is an array of "words" (2 bytes), so this is almost certainly a pointer increment.

**This looks *very* inefficient; it's only singly recursive so it could very easily be written as a loop.**  e.g. `do { something with *p++;  } while(--cx);` in C, i.e. a loop with `dec cx / jnz` at the bottom.

Also the branching is pretty silly: it could check for the recursion termination condition a lot earlier, before saving as many registers.  And it could take the `jmp` out of the normal path through the function by using `jna done`.  Maybe it would need to jump to a special block at the end of the function, putting 2 jumps on the special-case path, but that's still better than having 2 jumps on the main path.

Also storing/reloading stuff to `[bp+6]` is weird.  Does this function return by modifying one of its args on the stack?  It looks that way based on `pop dx` right after the call.  I hope this is intentionally obfuscated, or written as a starting point for optimization, because this looks highly over-complicated.

Based on the branch target names, I assume it's just finding the max signed word in an array, given a pointer and length.  That's trivial and vastly more efficient with a loop.